# Docker Image on Google Cloud Exiting (No detached mode)

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-registry, google-container-registry

I have a docker image on the container registry of google. The issue i'm facing is that it I do not see an option to add docker run-type arguments like:
--detached

I would run my container by calling

```
docker run -t -d -p 3333:3333 -p 3000:3000 --name <name> <image_ID>
```

Im using a VM instance on Gcloud and the container option seems to not have this detached argument (which is killing my ubuntu-based container from stopping when not used). Both using the Computing Engine OS and Google Cloud Run service option eventually results in an error.

Comment: Are you using Compute Engine Container Optimized OS? Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Your question lacks detail. Questions benefit from details including the specific steps that were taken, the errors that resulted or the steps that were taken to diagnose the error etc.

I assume from your question that you're using Cloud Console to create a Compute Engine instance and your're selecting "Container" to deploy a container image to it.

The default configuration is to run the container detached i.e. equivalent to  `docker run --detach`.

You can prove this to yourself by SSH'ing in to the instance and running e.g. `docker container ls` to see the running containers or `docker container ls --all` to see all containers (stopped too).

You can also run the container directly from here too as you would elsewhere although you may prefer to `docker run --interactive --stdin` or `docker container logs ...` to determine why it's not starting correctly :

```bash
docker run \
--stdin \
--detach \
--publish=3333:3333 \
--publish=3000:3000 \
--name=<name> \
<image_ID>
```

Comment: I added a bit more detail but it i'm no expert, i tried both the Computing Engine and the Google cloud run option. My image is quite large so I did not do the last option of just pulling it to an instance and docker running the image. Just to be clear, it is detached by default but there seems no option to expose ports when deploying it within the Computing Engine OS?

Comment: When you use Cloud Console to create a Compute Engine instance and deploy a container (or you use the equivalent `gcloud compute instances create-with-container`), the container is bound to the host's network. This is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/configuring-options-to-run-containers#publishing_container_ports). There is a 1:1 mapping container:host ports. You must program the firewall to expose ports as needed. Cloud Run is different. With Cloud Run, you get a single port. You must either specify it at deployment or use the default 8080.